# Can I use an SVG image as an button icon?

Tags: svg, icons, codenameone

Is this possible at all? I call `Image.createSVG(...)` and receive an `Image` object without any errors. I then call `Button.setIcon()`. But there's no icon on the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check `Image.isSVGSupported()` which currently will always return false.

Back in the day J2ME supported SVG thru one of the JSR's. No platform since has supported SVG natively with the exception of the web so this doesn't work on any of the modern platforms and we didn't bother implementing this even for the JavaScript port.

In the future we'd like to have a more efficient/portable way of supporting SVG e.g.: https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/1890